# As a NodeJS user, how do I use the ruby OpenSSL library for crypto?

Tags: ruby, node.js, encryption

I'm Node developer, but every once in awhile I get to play around with ERB templates. I really *love* pulling out as much ruby as I can in these templates when I can and this idea caught my eye especially.

I have this configuration value, which should be encrypted, but is coming in plain text. The program would decrypt it like so:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', 'e20jhciwjf90u2r9u9ujj');
var decrypted = crypto.update('4ufujj90u19ru90u109u') + crypto.final();
```

I was wondering how I might go about creating an encrypted string for the above to decrypt using ruby?

So far I have:

```
require 'openssl'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes256');
cipher.key= 'e20jhciwjf90u2r9u9ujj'

encrypted = cipher.update('my cat is yellow and very pretty.') + cipher.final
```

Two problems I have:

1. I often get a `Key length not long enough error` on the ruby side.
2. Ruby outputs a bunch of crazy hex, whereas node seems to always take/want `utf8`.
3. Am I encrypting/decrypting safely?
4. Is there a way to universally translate/work laterally with these two APIs?

Answer (score 0):

1. AES-256 uses a key of 256bits, and by default ruby uses utf-8 encoding, so each ansi character is 8bit long. So the key string must be 32 bytes.
2. Explicitly use an aes mode (e.g. aes-256-cbc).
3. Set the same iv(initial vector) on both sides

I finally succeeded with the above methods.
Here is my code:
Ruby side:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.iv = 'a'*16;
cipher.key = '01234567890123456789012345678901' # should be 32 characters, 32*8=256 bits
enc = Base64.strict_encode64(cipher.update('01234567890123456789012345678901') + cipher.final)
puts enc
```

Javascript side:

```
var encrypted = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', '01234567890123456789012345678901', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
var dec = decipher.update(encrypted);
console.log(Buffer.concat([dec, decipher.final()]));
```

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Indeed. I just want to make my code simple, but don't put it in your production environment

Comment: @AlexWang do yo know why then I can use a 6 character string for the key with Node, but I can't do the same for Ruby?

Comment: Node appends 0 to your key and makes it 256bits